# Planning a visit to Africa (Kenya), which other wildlife parks are worth going?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, national-parks, africa, kenya

We are a group of 6 and are planning a wildlife safari/trip to Africa with our starting point being Nairobi, Kenya during the month of September 2017. According to the itinerary received by the various tour organisers include only Masai Mara, Lake Nakuru, Amboseli National Park and Mt. Kenya. I can stretch my stay to 12 days, need some more places to visit, mostly wildlife reserves. Should we consider visiting Tanzania for Serengeti National Park?

Comment: Basically we are going for wildlife safari tours, so any other places which we can include in our itinerary would be helpful.

Comment: @pnuts Regardless of what the asker thinks is worthwhile, the question is still opinion-based. We're looking for questions that would be useful to people in the future, not just to the asker. (There used to be a "too localized" close reason that essentially meant, "The answer to this question won't be useful to anyone else.")

Comment: @pnuts I agree that if the askers tastes were as simple as "giraffes", then the question would apply to others. On the other hand, one would expect a simple query such as "Where's the best place to see giraffes?" would easily be answered by the basic research that we expect askers to do before posting here.

Comment: @pnuts English totally needs more versions of "we". There are some languages that have four of them: me and you, me and another person who isn't you, me and a bunch of people including you, me and a bunch of people not including you.

Comment: @pnuts No idea, sorry. But, hey, if it is Swahili, then my irrelevant comment is actually tangentially relevant! :-)